# SQL: Check constraint depends on other tables

Tags: sql, check-constraints

I have 3 tables: Member, Employer, and Location.

**Member** has MemberID, EmployerID, and LocationID. 
**Employer** has EmployerID.
**Location** has EmployerID, LocationID.

```
Member <<---> Employer
Location <<---> Employer
Member <---> Location
```

I need to make a check constraint on member that says

> A member's location is either null, or a location belonging to its employer

How do I constrain Member.LocationID to a location having the same EmployerID? ie: `Member.EmployerID = Location.EmployerID`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a unique index/primary key on `Location (EmployerID, LocationID)` (I take it that this may well be the case already)

Then have a multi column FK referencing that from `Member`

```
CREATE TABLE Location
(
EmployerID INT,
LocationID INT,
PRIMARY KEY (EmployerID,LocationID)
)


CREATE TABLE Member
(
MemberID INT PRIMARY KEY,
EmployerID INT,
LocationID INT,
FOREIGN KEY (EmployerID,LocationID)
    REFERENCES Location (EmployerID,LocationID)
)
```